# Compare if let in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I used this code

```
  if let breedVaccRecorddStr = self.petInfoDict.objectForKey("breedvaccinationrecord")  {

        }else{
            ALToastView.toastInView(UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow, withText: "No Data Found")
        }
```

This is my response

```
 {
        breed = dabour;
        breedvaccinationrecord = "";
        "city_registration" = 123146515;
        "date_of_birth" = "12-10-2014";
        "emergency_contacts" = 1245749876;
        gender = male;
        "owner_name" = Environmental;
        "pt_id" = 4150;
        "pt_images" = "";
        "pt_name" = demo123;
        ptinfo = "http://www.petcsi.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/jacky42.jpg";
        "prop_name" = "Bella Vida Estates";
        "qr_tag" = 5215653454;
        species = test;
        "vaccination_records" = test123;
        vaccinationrecord = "";
        "vet_info" = "";
    },
```

Constant can't be nil so it execute if block. but i am expecting output "No Data Found". their may be image url in that key how to check this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not very clear, but I'm guessing that your problem is `breedvaccinationrecord` contains an empty string, not nil. The `if let` construct by itself only tests for nil, which is why it's not working for you. However, you can also use a `where` clause:

```
let value = self.petInfoDict.objectForKey("breedvaccinationrecord")
if let breedVaccRecorddStr = value where value != ""  {
    // do your stuff
} else {
    ALToastView.toastInView(UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow, withText: "No Data Found")
}
```

This will execute the `else` if `breedvaccinationrecord` is nil or an empty string.

Comment: breedvaccinationrecord give may image url i want check it nil on not.

Comment: Your code already checks `breedvaccinationrecord` is not nil. I don't understand your question.

Comment: I am getting "" string in if let block.

Comment: I know. That's why I answered with `where value != ""`. It means the `if let` will fail and the `else` will execute.

Answer (score 0):

You should write another if let statement for nil value you expected. Such as:

```
if let imageString = self.petInfoDict.objectForKey("ptInfo") as String {
//Do something with the string
}
else {

}
```